# User Profile Sync service not updating the profiles

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, profile-sync

I have been trying to run the user profile configuration in SP 2013 but the profiles are not getting updated. I configured sync connections, assigned proper account but it just pulls 8 profiles out of 300 odd. What can be the issue? Also the full synchronisation completes in 5 minutes

Comment: Did you see any thing in logs? any connection filter? are you using ADI or User Profile sync?

Comment: User Profile sync

Comment: any connection filter? and did you select the correct OU while configuring the connection.

Comment: i am not using any connection filter, also selecting entire container.

Comment: What are you seeing in the Sync Client logs?

Answer (score 0):

Things you can check:

1. Grant the Replicate Directory Changes for the account which runs the service.
2. Select the containers where the users are stored.
3. Make sure if you have a multi farm setup, that the service is only running once.
4. Allow login locally for the account.
5. User Profile Service and User Profile Sync Service are Started successfully.

Hope this could help a little.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have followed all the above mentioned steps but still facing the issue. I noted one peculiar thing- even though I start Full Synchronization, in the timer jobs it shows user profile - Incremental Synchronization running.

Comment: Account that runs the service" be clear here, this is not the FARM account, it's the account that you entered when you created the Import Connection. Did the UPSS provision correctly? Are you running in on ONLY one server?